# trying to reuse components in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm fairly new in vue.js and i'm trying to do an app where you can find books but i'm stuck at the moment to reuse components.
When i open the app, the bookList component is used to show the most viewed books.
What i want to do is:
Search books from the input field and fill the bookList component with the response and then render it in the same view.
Here is my code. Any suggestion are welcome

```
<div id="app">
  <nav id="menu">
    <input type="text" v-model="newSearch" />
  </nav>

  <main id="panel">
    <header>
      <button class="toggle-button">☰</button>
      <!-- <books :books="books" :url="url"></books> -->
      <router-view></router-view>
    </header>
  </main>
</div> <!-- end app -->

<template id="book-list-template">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="book in books">
      <div class="content">
        <a v-link="{ name: 'book', params: { bookId: book.ID } }">
          <img :src="book.thumbnail" class="center-block">
          <p>{{book.title}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<template id="single-book-template">
  <div class="content" v-for="book in book">
    <img :src="book.cover" class="center-block prueba">
    <p>{{book.title}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

url = 'api_url'
//defining some components
var bookList = Vue.extend({
    template: '#book-list-template',
    data: function() {
        return {
            books: [],
        }
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.getBooks();
    },
    methods: {
        getBooks: function() {
            this.$http.jsonp(url+'criteria=most_viewed').then(function(response) {
                this.$set('books', response.data);
            }, function(response) {
                alert(response.status);
            });
        }
    }
});


var singleBook = Vue.extend({
    template: '#single-book-template',
    data: function() {
        return {
            book: ''
        }
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.getBookById();
    },
    methods: {
        getBookById: function() {
            this.$http.jsonp(url+'id='+this.$route.params.bookId).then(function(response) {
                this.$set('book', response.data);
            }, function(response) {
                alert(response.status);
            });
        }
    }
});

//creating a vue instance
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      newSearch: ''
    }
}) //end vue

var App = Vue.extend({})

var router = new VueRouter()

router.map({
    '/': {
        component: bookList
    },
    'book/:bookId': {
        name: 'book',
        component: singleBook
    }
})

router.start(App, '#app')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a `book list` template that handles the searching and filtering of the book list, and then a `book` template that handles displaying an individual book.  So it might look something like this:

```
<template id="book-list-template">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchText">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="book in books | filterBy searchText">
      <single-book :book="book"></single-book>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<template id="single-book-template">
  <div class="content">
    <img :src="book.cover" class="center-block prueba">
    <p>{{book.title}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

So the list template just generates a bunch of single-book templates.  The list handles the loading and filtering of the books (using a search bar or otherwise) and the book template handles any function of each individual book (ie. "add to my reading list" or an "order book" button.  In your single book template, you'd need to add a `prop` of book (instead of having that as a `data` property) so it can accept a book from your list template.

```
var singleBook = Vue.extend({
    template: '#single-book-template',
    props: ['book']
    }
});

var bookList = Vue.extend({
template: '#book-list-template',
data: function() {
    return {
        books: [],
        searchText:""
    }
},
ready: function() {
    this.getBooks();
},
methods: {
    getBooks: function() {
        this.$http.jsonp(url+'criteria=most_viewed').then(function(response) {
            this.$set('books', response.data);
        }, function(response) {
            alert(response.status);
        });
    }
},
components:{
    "single-book":singleBook
}
});
```

Lastly, add an input to your book-list component that allows users to search for a book.  You can model that to data called `searchText`.  Then you can use Vue's filterBy on your `v-for="book in books | filterBy searchText"`

Comment: I didn't include any router information because I think most of what you've got here would be handled with a single component.  If you want to write another component with more in-depth information about a book and map that to `/book/:id`, then you could make each book in this component a link to that URL.

Comment: Thanks! that worked.
Can yu give me another hint?
I have a side menu in my app where is going to be all my options. I want the input search in that menu not inside the book-list template.
How can i bind my input search with the bookList component data?
I want to render in that component the response from my request.
I hope had been clear.
Thanks a lot @Jeff

Answer (score -1):

You *may* be looking for the `keep-alive` directive. If you `Ctrl + F` and search "keep-alive" here you'll find it: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html